# Get return value from new class with gui

Tags: java, swing

I have a  class that extends JFrame to make orders.
in the middle I have a button that opens a new window that is used to find an article.

What I need is:
When I click btnNewArticle, after searching new article, and confirm in new window, I will get as return article code.

Click btnNewArticle --> (open new window to find an article) --> confirm selection -->as return I get Article Code.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: check aioobe's answer, It is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this principle has worked:

```
public class ArticleSearchDialog extends JDialog {

    public static ArticleId execute(Frame parent) {
        ArticleSearchDialog dialog = new ArticleSearchDialog(parent, true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        return dialog.getSelectedArticle();
    }

    private ArticleId getSelectedArticle() {
        return selectedArticle;
    }

    private void jbCancelActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        selectedArticle = null;
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }

    private void jbOkActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        selectedArticle = ...; //TODO 
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }        

    // All the rest of the dialog code.
}
```

Then the call gets really easy:

```
ArticleId articleId = ArticleSearchDialog.execute(this);
if (articleId != null) {
    //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Java dialogs: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

In the above tutorial, they explain how to do custom dialogs such as the one below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/CustomizedDialog2Metal.png))</sub>

They handle return-values by giving the child-dialog a reference to it's parent dialog, in which it fills in the relevant values upon closing.

Comment: to be honest i am lost.
in OrdersFrame i have:
protected void newArticle_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  new NewArticle();
 }
 
 and in NewArticle:
 protected void saveArticle_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  //code to do
  this.dispose();
  }
  
i realy dont know what to do to get ArticleCode on return.

and from Java Dialogs example i dont understand much

HELP

Comment: Give the OrdersFrame a reference to the "parent" dialog, that is, the GUI that spawns the OrdersFrame. In `code to do this.dispose()` you do something like `parent.setChosenArticleCode(codeFromDialog)`.

Comment: can you check whats wrong with my code? i sent http://CodeTidy.com/217/ (what is Orders..) and on line 260 there is a NuovaRiga method. http://CodeTidy.com/218/ (NuovaRiga) and on line 199 there is Save() action....